# Eclipse custom hotkey - print current line to standard out

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, content-assist

Eclipse has a useful hotkey to assign current line to a local variable - when I type for instance:

```
Math.random()
```

and press `ALT + SHIFT + L` (Extract local variable), I can quickly change the line to

```
double random = Math.random();
```

I would like to use the same trick for printing it to std out, so that the `Math.random()` is being changed to:

```
System.out.println(Math.random());
```

Currently the fastet way to to this is to type `syso` and use content assist to use a template, but that requires manual copy pasting. Anyone knows a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to my mind to achieve your goal, but both of them require the selection of statement first.

After you select statement, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, then type `syso` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Selected statement will be placed inside `System.out` block:

```
System.out.println(statement);
```

---

Also you can prepare eclipse template (**Window->Preference->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Templates**), and give it some name:

```
System.out.println(${line_selection});${cursor}
```

After you select statement, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or select menu option **Source->Surround With** (also in context menu). Template you have created should be there so select it. Selected statement will be wrapped inside desired block of code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no shortcut available from the keys section of preferences. Is content assist really not fast enough for you in this case?

Comment: Well, I'm just doing this out of curosity. There are some possible custom templates configurations - I wonder if the thing I would like to do is achievable at all.

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F